# Use the bisection method to find the minimum of the function

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

Use the bisection method to find the minimum of the function is $f(x)= 3x^2–4x+1$ over the interval $[0,2]$
. Determine the optimal value of $x$ within $5\%$ of the initial interval and 
How many function evaluations are needed to get within x* ± 0.001?

My attempt

The first iteration 
$a=0,b=2, m=(a+b)/2=1$

$f(a)=1, f(b)=5, f(m)=0$

$x^*=6x-4=0$

$x^*=2/3=0.6667$

I do not understand what the first part question is asking.Is it mean that I need to continue the evaluation until I find the value of $b-a$ is closed to $0.05$? After the 11 evaluations , I get $a=0.3321$ and $b=0.3341$.But $x*=0.6667$ instead of $0.3333$

Comment: I think you need to think about the criterion by which you decide whether to take the left-hand interval, or the right-hand interval at each step. Normally, bisection is used to find roots of continuous functions, where, by using the Intermediate Value Theorem, you just choose the interval such that the function changes sign on that interval. Using calculus, or even algebra, we can see that the minimum occurs at $x=\dfrac23$.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old question, I felt it merited a response.

Then answer Adrian is mixing two concepts - root finding using the bisection method, and minimisation.

However, for the minimisation, it would indeed depend on whether you chose the first $[a,m]$ or second $[m,b]$ interval to determine the minimum, but that is not directly related to whether the function changes sign in the numerical method, but whether the *derivative* changes sign, so one could indeed solve the derivative function for 0 using the bisection method, but that is not the question.

What is needed is to take both intervals $[a, m]$ and $[m,b]$ and then calculate the midpoints of *those*, lets call them $a_1$ and $b_1$. Then to determine the value of the function at these midpoints. If $f(a_1) < f(a)$ and $f(a_1) < f(m)$ then you replace $b$ by $m$, and go round the loop finding the midpoint of the interval $[a,a_1]$ and $[a_1,m]$ and so on.

If neither condition is true, then test for $f(b_1) < f(m)$ and $f(b_1) < f(b)$. If both of these are true, then set $a = m$ and start again.

If none of these conditions are true, then either:

i) the interval does not contain a genuine minima, only the extreme of the function at either $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ or:

ii) you minima happens to be m.

If your issue is ii) then starting again, with a slightly different interval would likely resolve this.

Technically, numerically simply solving $f'(x) = 0$ for $x = x_{min}$ and then evaluating $f''(x_{min})$ would give the solution, but that is not finding the minimum by the numerical method, that is solving for the root of the derivative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).